# controlfx dialog usage to include the dialog inside the catch block

Tags: java, javafx, controlsfx

I want to show exception stacktrace as soon as an exception is caught in the 
catch block. I am referring to the doc for ControlFX [here](https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/src/e47cc550571abffff0ee56ea0f27683655cb076a/controlsfx/src/main/java/org/controlsfx/dialog/Dialogs.java?at=default#cl-532). Do I just need to copy 
a part of code and paste it inside the catch block to get the dialog open? Please let me know.

```
 try{

 }
 catch (SQL Exception ex){

  public Action showException(Throwable exception) {
        Dialog dlg = buildDialog(Type.ERROR);
        dlg.setContent(exception.getMessage());
        dlg.setExpandableContent(buildExceptionDetails(exception));
        return dlg.show();
    }


 }
```

Doing the above generates lot of errors and I am sure something is wrong.

**Changes Done After Moving the Code from Catch into Try block are shown in the Image [image]**:

The error shown in the line #143  above, is as follows despite having imported
`import org.controlsfx.control.action.Action;
import org.controlsfx.dialog.Dialogs;`

[image: line #143]

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring a method in a catch block, which is illegal syntax. Declare the `showException` method outside of the method in which the catch block resides, and simply call the `showException` from within the catch block.

You are also importing the wrong `Dialog`.  Your import statements are importing `java.awt.Dialog` (or something like that).  It is not importing `org.controlsfx.dialog.Dialog`.

Comment: Thanks, I made the changes and updated the results in my post. It's still showing errors. Don't know why `show()` is striked through.

Comment: A strikethrough generally means the method is deprecated. The Javadoc for that method might say why. What errors are you getting?

Comment: @jewelsea When I do `import org.controlsfx.dialog.Dialog;`, I get an error `java.awt.Dialog is already
defined in a single-type import`. However, defining `import org.controlsfx.dialog.Dialogs;`
doesn't throws any error.

Answer (score 0):

Don't import `java.awt.Dialog`; you have the correct imports mentioned. You also appear to have the `showException` method still defined in another method, specifically in the try block. You cannot declare a method inside of a method.

Comment: I am not importing `java.awt.Dialog; `. I am importing `import org.controlsfx.dialog.Dialog;` and I am wondering why I am getting ` an error `java.awt.Dialog is already defined in a single-type import`. If I can't define `showException()` inside try-catch block, then how should I go about showing a dialog as soon as exception occurs? By the way `showException()` method doesn't throw any errors when I declare it inside the catch block.

Comment: Declare it like a standard method in java. Your import error may be because you have a `java.awt.*` import, and so the compiler cannot distinguish the type to use for the dialog declaration. You can fix this by fully qualifying the type of dialog to use, i.e. `org.controlsfx.dialog.Dialog` instead of just `Dialog`. Also, i just caught my double answer and would like to apologize for not editing my first one or providing a comment.